# For loop "broken"? Includes "if bool = true" but i doesn't stop at i < int for "else"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, for-loop

I've come across a weird problem which I can't solve, no matter what i tried. Maybe I'm just overlooking something elemental but I've completely run out of ideas so I certainly hope anybody can help me.

I have a for-loop which doesn't work properly. Interesting enough, an almost identical one works just fine.
The problem is, that it doesn't stop (apparently) when i < int but instead keeps going which (of course) throws an IndexOutOfBounds exception at an Array. I'm bad at explaining this I guess so i'll just "let the code speak": [NOTE: I edited out method calls and other stuff which - I can assure - has nothing to do with the problem, to make the code more readable]

```
for (int i = GeneralVars.intStartAtLine; i < (GeneralVars.intEndAtLine + 1); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 49; j++)
        a++;
    if (boolCheck == true)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            if (z[i].zahlen7[j].nummer != 0)
            {
                if ((z[i].zahlen7[j + 1].nummer - z[i].zahlen7[j].nummer) == 1)
                {
                    //dosomestuff
                }
            }
        }
        if (z[i].zahlen7[0].nummer != 0)
        {
            if (a == b)
            {
                //do some stuff
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; i++)
            if ((z[i].zahlen[j + 1].nummer - z[i].zahlen[j].nummer) == 1)
            {
                //dosomestuff
            }
        if (a == b)
        {
           //dosomestuff
        }
    }
}
```

So, the problem occurs in the else-loop, as mentioned before, to be precise, the IndexOutOfBounds exception occurs here

```
if ((z[i].zahlen[j + 1].nummer - z[i].zahlen[j].nummer) == 1)
```

The reason why it happens is, because 'i' here is 3417, although it can't be? I checked the variables with various break points, Genervars.intEndAtLine is always 3416. i < GeneralVars.intEndAtLine + 1 should never reach 3417, yet it does. I also tried a simple work-around for testing purposes by adding the line

```
if (i != 3417)
```

before and after the else-loop, yet it STILL enters it when (for whatever reason), i = 3417.

So - well - I'm completely lost here. Thanks in advance for any help I'll receive.

Last Note: I'm new here and I'm not a native english speaker, so in case I did any big mistakes, please forgive me :-)

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html

Comment: This code screams "job security".  :)

Comment: This is just private coding, no boss here to kick me out :-) But thanks for the link Hamish Grubijan, I'll definitely take a look at it and try to get used to a "cleaner" coding style.

Comment: From now on my favourite way of adding an integer constant (e.g. `48`) to a numeric variable (e.g. `a`) is: `for (int j = 0; j < 49; j++) a++;`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well

```
for (int j = 0; j < 5; i++) // are you sure you want to increase i here or should it be j?
{
...
}
```

For the last run, I guess i == 3416 and when you enter this loop for the second time, i == 3417 and you get the exception.

**Edit:** *Try to use constants instead of magic numbers. Your code would look much cleaner.*

Comment: DOUGH. Yeah, that was indeed the mistake. Guess I should just go to bed, apparently I can't concentrate enough to code anymore :-) Thanks a lot and sorry for wasting your time on such a lousy mistake!